# Can't performe ajax (domxml) request's using nginx+php-fpm (5.2.17)

Tags: ajax, nginx, php

I want migrate some of my php applications from apache+mod_php to nginx+php-fpm.
Everything is ok, but some of JavaScript stopped working.

Error is:

```
TypeError: mainTlistObject.xmlHttp.responseXML is null
```

Nginx returns 200 OK. But there are no xml data in responce.

Maybe I've miss some configure option (xml extensions?) in php

> ./configure --enable-fastcgi --enable-fpm --with-mcrypt --with-zlib
>   --enable-mbstring --enable-pdo --with-curl --disable-debug --with-pic --disable-rpath --enable-inline-optimization --with-bz2 --enable-xml --with-zlib --enable-sockets --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-pcntl --enable-mbregex --with-mhash --with-xsl --enable-zip --with-pcre-regex --with-gd --without-pdo-sqlite --with-pdo-mysql --without-sqlite --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-png-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-mysql --enable-bcmath --enable-calendar --enable-exif --enable-ftp --with-gettext --with-mysqli --with-kerberos=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-dbase --with-gmp --enable-shmop --enable-wddx --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/opt/php5.2

nginx part for php:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/opt/php5.2/php5.2.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi.conf;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault. Just forgot to specify "output_buffering = 4096" in php.ini